# Why trees are structured from up to down not as real trees the root is first to the ground?

Tags: data-structures, graph, tree

**Why trees are structured downward not as real trees the root is first to the ground?!**

Comment: You can basically draw the memory the way you like! You don't really have a byte right or left to another byte. Just like in a tree growing from root to leaves, your tree structure can be sketched upwards!

Comment: yes but it's known the wrong way (downward)!!

Comment: Conventions. Timeline in charts is often left-to-right, which is yet another convention.

Comment: I remember that Donald Knuth in his "The Art of Computer Programming" (first book) answered this question, unfortunately I don't remember exact answer (probably answer is not that impressive)

Comment: In his discussion of trees, Knuth says that he originally drew trees with the root at the bottom, but study of the literature at the time showed 80% of papers and books had trees with the root at the top. So he changed his representation. I, myself, have *rarely* seen trees drawn with the root at the bottom. If the idea of an upside down tree confuses you, just think of the roots of a real tree: they branch out underground.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you dont know before hand how hight it can grow when writing on paper.

Suppose you are explaining this problem to someone with an array, and you start drawing, you will need to know how much space to leave on a paper before beginning to draw.

This also has the problem in online publishing where user will need to scroll down, a lot, for a really complex tree to get to the root of a tree to understand the tree. Writing the root at the top solves this problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i think because human beings start writing on papers and sheets at the top.